# phpのfor文についてインクリメントが ++$i と $i++の時の結果が同じになるのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: php

ドキュメントを見たところ

```
<?php
$var = 0;
echo ++$var;//1
```

インクリメントが前にあるときは値が加算されたものを返すのはわかりました。

ただfor文をためしてみると疑問がおこりました。

```
$a = array("sugimoto", "taguti", "fkoji")
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); ++$i){
    echo $a[$i], PHP_EOL;
}
//sugimoto taguti fkoji
```

前インクリメントだと先にプラスになるから
//taguti fkoji
になりそうなものですが、この挙動はいったいなんなのでしょうか？
もしよろしければご教授願います。

Comment: 比較→インクリメント→for内処理→比較→。。。と考えれば納得できますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。書籍にしっかり書いてありました。比較→処理→インクリメントですね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「前インクリメントだと先にプラス」という動作の意味を誤解されているようです。前置インクリメントと後置インクリメントの違いは、「式としての値」を取得するのと「変数の内容をインクリメントする」ことの間での後・先になります。つまり、「式としての値」を使わない場所では、前置でも後置でも全く同じ動作になります。

phpに限らずC言語スタイルの`for`文:

```
for( 初期化; 判定; 更新 ) {
    ループの中身
}
```

という文は厳密に次のようなコードと同じ順序で評価されます。

```
初期化;
while( 判定 ) {
    ループの中身
    更新;
}
```

「更新」の中身に、前置インクリメントがあるからと言って、この順序が変更されることはありません。

また「判定」のところに記述した式は、その値が使われてループを続行するのかどうかの判定に使われますが、「初期化」「更新」に書いた式の値は使われません。(例えば`$i = 0`という式の値は`0`になるのですが、その`0`という値は使われません。)

従って、式の値が使われない場所に書いてある前置インクリメントと後置インクリメントの動作には全く違いが見られないということになります。

---

逆に「判定」のところに書いた式は、その式の値が使われますから、結果に差が出てきます。インクリメントではなくデクリメントですが、次のような`for`文の動作を確かめてみられると良いでしょう。

```
for( $i = 10; --$i; ) {
    echo $i;
}

for( $i = 10; $i--; ) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確認しまいした前デクリメントだと$i が 0 になまるで実行されることがわかりました。しかしまた新たな疑問が生じました勉強します。

Comment: @matomebutai さん、 「変数の値」と「式の値」が別物というのは、なかなか慣れるまで難しいかもしれません。ネットや本で調べても解決できない疑問は、他にも疑問に思っておられる方がたくさんいる可能性があると思って、当サイトのようなQ&Aサイトもうまく活用して慣れていってください。

Answer (score 3):

セミコロンで区切られた各式、`$i = 0` と `$i < count($a)` と `++$i` はそれぞれ独立しています。

下記のように考えてみてください。

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($a)) {
    echo $a[$i], PHP_EOL;
    ++$i;
}
```

独立した文なので、最後のインクリメントが`++$i`か`$i++`かは、他の行の実行結果に影響しません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
インクリメントは最後に行われることがわかりました。